# Python 3 Regex extract part of string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have tried all the StackOverflow solutions for similar questions, and could`t find anything.

I have this snippet of code and I need to extract the text between html tags, everything between > and < .

```
word = "div class="name">
                        Text_I_Want_To_Extract 
                    </div>"

m = re.search('>(.+)<', word)
print (m)
```

I have tried various regex expressions but I failed. I always get empty result. I am guessing it is because I am extracting everything between > and < symbols.

Did anyone had this kind of problems with Python 3 ?

Comment: `m = re.search('>(.+)<', word, flags=re.DOTALL)` ?

Comment: Why you shouldn't parse HTML with regular expressions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/247696

Comment: Use a proprer HTML parser like BeautifulSoup

Comment: @Rakesh, very close to solution, I just have a lot of /t added to the string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `flags`

**Ex:**

```
import re

word = """div class="name">
                        Text_I_Want_To_Extract 
                    </div>"""

m = re.search('>(.+)<', word, flags=re.DOTALL)
print (m.group(1).strip())
```

**Output:**

```
Text_I_Want_To_Extract
```

Comment: Yes, this works. Thank you !

Comment: You are welcome :)